# Cannot grab data inside a div ContentPlaceHolder1_contractCodeDiv in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good day. I am trying to grab some data from a url. Specifically, I wanted to grab what is inside **div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_contractCodeDiv"** and produce the output below. However, I am just getting an error. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/address/0x264ca80271e944c80ee81a3c8ed71acaa7d15b15#code"
url = requests.get(url, headers=header, timeout=5)
ca = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

constatus = ca.find('h3', class_='h6 text-dark font-weight-bold mb-4').get_text().strip()
print (constatus)

conFlag = ca.find('div', class_='alert alert-warning text-dark mb-2').get_text()
print ("conFlag: ", conFlag)

contractCode = ca.find('div', class_='ContentPlaceHolder1_contractCodeDiv').get_text()
print (contractCode)
```

Wanted Output:

```
Warning:  This contract contains unverified libraries: IterableMapping
Status: Contract Source Code Verified (Exact Match)
Contract Name: ElonVSPutin
Compiler Version:  v0.6.12+commit.27d51765
Optimization Enabled:  No with 200 runs
Other Settings: default evmVersion, MIT license

Compiler specific version warnings:       #-- text from the exclaimation icon
The compiled contract might be susceptible to SignedImmutables (very low-severity),
ABIDecodeTwoDimensionalArrayMemory (very low-severity), EmptyByteArrayCopy (medium-severity),
DynamicArrayCleanup (medium-severity) Solidity Compiler Bugs.
```

Current Output:

```
Contract Source Code Verified (Exact Match)
Warning:  ×This contract contains unverified libraries: IterableMapping
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like to print the texts? Take a look at the example - If you like to get the information separately you can access them by `css selector` that check for a string, get the parent and extract the text:

```
contract = soup.select_one('div:-soup-contains-own("Contract Name:")').parent.get_text(' ', strip=True)
compilerVersion = soup.select_one('div:-soup-contains-own("Compiler Version")').parent.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/address/0x264ca80271e944c80ee81a3c8ed71acaa7d15b15#code"
url = requests.get(url, headers=header, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

info = '\n'.join([e.replace('\n\n',' ').strip('\n ×') for e in soup.select_one('#ContentPlaceHolder1_contractCodeDiv').text.split('\n\n\n\n') if e != ''])
warning = soup.select_one('#ContentPlaceHolder1_divWarningMsg').text.strip().replace(':','\n')

print(f'{info}\n{warning}')
```

#### Output

```
This contract contains unverified libraries: IterableMapping
Contract Source Code Verified (Exact Match)
Contract Name: ElonVSPutin
Compiler Version v0.6.12+commit.27d51765
Optimization Enabled: No with 200 runs
Other Settings: default evmVersion, MIT license

Compiler specific version warnings
The compiled contract might be susceptible to SignedImmutables (very low-severity), ABIDecodeTwoDimensionalArrayMemory (very low-severity), EmptyByteArrayCopy (medium-severity), DynamicArrayCleanup (medium-severity) Solidity Compiler Bugs.
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working. I would like to ask if how can I assign variable name to every line. For example: var1 -  This contract contains unverified libraries: IterableMapping  var2 -  Contract Source Code Verified (Exact Match) and so on..

Comment: Happy to help - You could but this is predestined to [ask  a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - Unpacking your list is one approache `var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,*_ = [e.replace('\n\n',' ').strip('\n ×') for e in soup.select_one('#ContentPlaceHolder1_contractCodeDiv').text.split('\n\n\n\n') if e != '']
`  but you do not have that much control, better use my first suggestion, to extract the specific information. So you could handle case if it do not exist.